# Calling parent function

Tags: c#, list, function, memory, parent

I have the following code/function in my parent form (memory):

```
    List<int> ControleList = new List<int>(); 

    private void Controle(int controlenummer){

        ControleList.Add(controlenummer);

        if (ControleList.Count == 2)
        {
            if (ControleLijst[0] == ControleLijst[1])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("They are the same!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("They don't match...");
            }
            ControleList.Clear();
        }
    }
```

And in my child form I want to use this function, I currently have this (which isn't working):

```
    private void pcbKaart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Memory.Controle(Waarde);
    }
```

So i wondered how I still can use this function because making it static won't work for me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `Form`, so could you:

```
((Memory)this.Parent).Controle(Waarde);  //or is it _this.Owner_?
```

And you will have to make that Parent's method `public`.

Further, if this an `MDI` situation, you can change it to:

```
((Memory)this.MdiParent).Controle(Waarde);
```